# switchMap only cancelling some endpoints

Tags: http, rxjs, get, cancellation, switchmap

I have a form control input to search for results.

`component.html`

```html
<input matInput [formControl]="input">
```

I'm using `valueChanges` observable to check for changes.

`component.ts`

```js
this.xx = this.input.valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap(res => {
    return this.someService.test(res);
  }),
);
```

What i don't understand is that on fast typing the cancellation of the previous http request is only working on some of the endpoints.

`someService.ts`

```js
public test(q: string): Observable<any> {
  // api-1 cancelling
  return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/geosuggestion?q=' + q);
  // api-2 not cancelling
  // return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/items?q=' + q, { headers: { 'auth-token': this.authService.getToken() } });
}
```

Similar questions always origin from the fact that they used different obsersvable chains. In my case there has to be a different reason as i'm using the exact same logic in both cases and only replace the endpoint url.

`api-1 (successfully cancelling)`
[image: api-1 screenshot]

`api-2 (not cancelling)`
[image: api-2 screenshot]

Why is switchMap cancellation only working on some of my endpoints?

Comment: did you try debouncetime?

Comment: i could use debouncetime altough that would not solve the problem (for example long lasting requests). also i don't like the idea of adding artificial transmit lags